# ¿Cómo poder programar en multicore sobre un dataframe de pandas?

Tags: python

Se quiere realizar la optimización de funciones que están definidas sobre un dataset de pandas para la ejecución multinúcleo, de funciones como lo es la raíz cuadrada, el logaritmo, calcular el inverso, hacer la suma, multiplicación, división, sobre todo el conjunto de variables del dataframe, es decir implementar funciones como la siguiente en paralelo:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.read_csv("data1_path.csv")
data2 = pd.read_csv("data2_path.csv")
def cuadrado(DF):
    aux_DF = pd.DataFrame()    
    for i in DF.keys():
        aux_DF[i + str(**2)] = DF[i]*DF[i]
    return aux_DF

def suma(DF1, DF2):
    aux_DF = pd.Data_Frame()
    for i in DF1.keys()
        for j in DF2.keys():
            aux_DF[i + str(+) + j] = DF1[i] + DF2[j]
    return aux_DF

cudrado = cuadrado(data1)
suma = suma(data1, data2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Recomiendo mirar el paquete swifter y vectorizar las funciones que se quieran utilizar. Por ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import swifter

def square(x):
    return np.square(x)

aux_DF['alguna_columna^2'] = DF['alguna_columna'].swifter.apply(square)
```

Paraleliza las operaciones automáticamente.